# how to dynamically highlight text in an html document

Tags: javascript, html, highlight

I have a couple of elements in a HTML page (which don't share a tag type) in which I want to highlight all instances of a word inputted by the user.  My thought was that I could do this by using the replace function to replace all instances of say "fox" with

```
<font class='highlight'>fox</font>
```

My question is, how can I make these elements identifiable?  I tried using class but my company's version of IE doesn't support getElementsByClassName.  Does anyone know of a better way to do it?

An example of what my page might look like

```
<body>
    <h1>All about foxes</h1>
    <font>I'm a fox</font>
</body>
```

Just to make the point about how they're different types of tags.  In that example, if the user entered "fox", fox in the h1 tag and the font tag would be highlighted.  Obviously something has to be used to identify the h1 and the font tags as part of some group that I can grab all the members of.

Because the content being displayed on the page is also determined dynamically, I need a way to do this using Javascript.

EDIT:
An addition to the previous code example.

```
<body>
    <h1>All about foxes</h1>
    <font>I'm a fox</font>
    <h3>I'm not a fox</h3>
</body>
```

I need to a way to mark the h1 and font tags specifically (not saying that all h1's and font's should be marked) so that they will highlight and the h3 won't (as well as any other instances of fox on the page).  Additionally, it's a pain to include external JS files in my environment (or any external file for that matter).  For that reason I'd prefer it if I didn't have to use JQuery.

Comment: Use a `regex` to find the text.

Comment: You might use $('.class').css() method in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got `class='highlight'` in the appropriate places, you can use the following, which is functionally equivalent to `getElementsByClassName`:

```
elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for ( i=0; i<elems.length; i++ )
{
  if ( elems[i].className == "highlight" )
     { elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; }
}
```

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/XU8Qz/

Just do whatever style changes you need to in place of setting the background color to yellow.